# QComboBox on clicked signal doesn't let me select old rows in PyQt5 Table Widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

I wanted to show a CopmboBox when the user select a single cell, I verify what column is the cell he clicked and if it's the 4th column I'll show a combo box in this way:

```
  def chiusura(self):
    self.accept()
  def generariga(self):       
    nulla = None
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Viaggi (Codice_cliente) VALUES (?)', nulla)
    c.commit()
    self.datitabella()
    delegate = MyDelegate(self)
  def __init__(self):
    super(modificaviaggi, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('modifica_reg.ui', self)
    bottonefinestragenera = self.bottone_aggiungiriga
    bottonefinestragenera.clicked.connect(self.generariga)
    bottonetorna = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'bottone_torna') 
    bottonetorna.clicked.connect(self.chiusura)
    self.tabella_registrazioni.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    self.showdata()
  def showdata(self):
    customers = [] 
    delegate = MyDelegate(self)
    tablerow = 0 
    conteggio = c.execute('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Viaggi').fetchone()[0]
    self.tabella_registrazioni.blockSignals(True)
    for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM Viaggi "):
        rigavalore = 0
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setRowCount(conteggio)
        for r in range(0, 19):
            self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, rigavalore, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[rigavalore])))
            rigavalore+= 1
        self.combo_customers = QComboBox()
        self.combo_customers.addItems(customers)
        tablerow+= 1
    self.tabella_registrazioni.blockSignals(False) 
    self.tabella_registrazioni.itemChanged.connect(self.changeIcon) 
    self.tabella_registrazioni.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
    self.tabella_registrazioni.clicked.connect(self.pressed) 
  def pressed(self, item):
    row = item.row()
    column = item.column()
    if column == 4:
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setCellWidget(row, column, self.combo_customers)
  def customers_combo(self, customers):
    for cu in d.execute("SELECT customers FROM CustomersTable "):
            customers.append(cu[0].strip())
  def changeIcon(self, item):
    row = item.row()
    col = item.column()
    zero = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 0).text()
    uno =  self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 1).text()
    if uno == 'None':
        uno = None 
    else:
        uno = uno
    due = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 2).text()
    tre = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 3).text()
    quattro = str(self.combo_customers.currentText())
    cinque = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 5).text()
    sei = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 6).text()
    sette = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 7).text()
    if sette == 'None':
       sette = None 
    else:
        sette = sette 
    otto = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 8).text()
    if otto == 'None':
        otto =  0 
    else:
        otto = otto 
    nove = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 9).text()
    if nove == 'None':
       nove = 0 
    else:
        nove = nove         
    dieci = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 10).text()
    if dieci == 'None':
       dieci = 0 
    else:
        dieci = dieci         
    unouno = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 11).text()
    if unouno == 'None':
       unouno = 0
    else:
        unouno = unouno
    unodue = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 12).text()
    unotre = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 13).text()
    unoquattro = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 14).text()
    unocinque = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 15).text()
    unosei = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 16).text()
    if unosei == 'None':
       unosei = 0
    else:
        unosei = unosei
    unosette = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 17).text()
    if unosette == 'None':
       unosette = 0 
    else:
        unosette = unosette
    unootto = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 18).text()
    c.execute('UPDATE Viaggi SET DataDDT = ?, Viaggio_N = ?, Codice_cliente = ?, Ragione_sociale = ?, Localita = ?, Provincia = ?, Giorno_consegna = ?, Peso_netto = ?, Peso_lordo = ?, Pallet_dati_piu = ?, Pallet_resi_meno = ?, Targa = ?, Autista = ?, Magazzino = ?, Articolo = ?, Prezzo = ?, Qta = ?, Note = ? WHERE ID = ?', 
                                            (uno, due, tre, quattro, cinque, sei, sette, otto, nove, dieci, unouno, unodue, unotre, unoquattro, unocinque, unosei, unosette, unootto, zero))
    c.commit()
```

This implementation works and shows me the combo box correctly if the columns selected is the 4th, the problem is that I can't selected the old cells; If I select the cell in column 4 row 3, and then I select another cell which is in column 4 row 4, if I want to select the column 4 row 3 I can't, It lets me select only "new" cells

Comment: Are there any contents to these comboboxes when you try to select their cell?  Please provide a minimal working example of your code.

Comment: Yes, the content of the comboboxes is the result of the query made in customers_combo

Comment: I don't see anything overtly wrong in the code you posted. If you can post more or create a minimal working example that  might help

Comment: I added some more details, maybe the change signal it's a problem for him?

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: I added  my whole code, at least I added all the functions called used

Comment: @IT-SRL No, that's *not* a MRE (where is the class definition? where is the code for the delegate?) You don't have to add the "whole code". You have to craft a specific example that we could copy, paste and run, possibly without any substantial modification. Also, please use standard (and consistent) indentation with 4 spaces.